# Child component re-render but data never appears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using map along with Table, however I cannot get it to work as this is my first ReactJS application.

Here is What I am doing:

```
        <table className="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                {this.state.itemList.map(this.addMemberRow)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Here is my addMemberRow funtion, I am not sure if it is correct!

```
addMemberRow(item, i) {
    return(
        <tr key={i}>    
            <td> {item} </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Here is my constructor

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            itemList: [],
        };
    this.addMemberRow = this.addMemberRow.bind(this);
    this.openAll = this.openAll.bind(this);
}
```

This above code is from child component of

In the App I have

```
this.setState({itemList: itemList});
```

So whenever I add something to the array, I call setState so that this child component re-renders. but the data never appears. Nor does anything else even If I put

```
<h1>bhavya</h1>
```

in place of

`{item}`

#### EDIT :

```
onUpdate(item){
    itemList.push(item);
    this.setState({itemList: itemList}, () => {
        alert(that.state.itemList.length);
    });
}
```

This is where I set the state. I get the alert everytime with updated length.

**EDIT 2 :**

my array is empty in the child component ! :( I did `console.dir(this.state.itemList)` as soon as I enter render in child component. It shows nothing in the console, but in browser console It shows Array which is empty!! :(

I pass the itemList

```
<AddList itemList={this.state.itemList}/>
```

and I also have

```
App.defaultProps = {
    itemList: []
};
```

and

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      itemList: [],
  };
  this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this);     
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: show the code above: `this.setState({itemList: itemList});` where you are building up the new array being assigned to `itemList`.

Comment: @gravityplanx :  Not even a single, but I am having a warning, 
<span> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. See App > AddList > tbody > span.
But then I remove {this.state.itemList.map(this.addMemberRow)}
and just place 
<h1>Test</h1> It gets printed. but the warning is still there. So I guessed that it might not be the problem at hand.

Comment: @xianwill : added the code in EDIT: section

Comment: what do you get in the console if you: `console.dir(this.state.itemList)` in the render function before your table markup?

Comment: @xianwill : nothing, my array is empty in the child component ! :( I did `console.dir(this.state.itemList)` as soon as I enter render in child component. It shows nothing in the console, but in browser console It shows `Array` which is empty!! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `itemList` state in `App`, and rendering `itemList` from state in `AddList` - a completely different component.

Thats not how state works. Only one component owns any particular state. If you are doing the update on the `itemList` state in your `App` component, `App` needs to pass the `itemList` down to the child component, and the child component needs to render from `props` -- not state. State is not shared between components. It is owned by one single component and then passed down for rendering through props.

Here is an example:

App's render method body:

```
return <AddList itemList={this.state.itemList} />
```

The line above passes `App`'s itemList state down to the `AddList` component as a prop.

AddList's render method body (**notice use of props**):

```
render() {
    var itemList = this.props.itemList;
    return (
        <table className="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
                {itemList && itemList.map(this.addMemberRow)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Here - AddList renders the itemList array that was passed down as a prop.

Comment: I commented out `this.state = {
            itemList: [],
        };`
In the constructor of child, and with the use of props, it shows  `console.dir(this.props.itemList);`  correct in console, but when I do `{this.props.itemList.map(this.addMemberRow)}`
 it gives an error in browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: are there cases where itemList is null? try changing your render to edited answer - it checks to make sure itemList is not undefined before invoking the map fn.

Comment: yes, when it is called for the first time, add button is not clicked, itemList is populated on add button click. If you have any suggestions, most welcome, I am trying to handle that.

Comment: did you notice this bit above `itemList && itemList.map(this.addMemberRow) ` - that should handle it. If itemList is null, the expression will short circuit as false and `map` will not be called until the itemList state is changed again and the component is rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this code:

```
onUpdate(item){
    itemList.push(item);
    this.setState({itemList: itemList});
    alert(that.state.itemList.length);
}
```

should be more like this:

```
onUpdate(item){
    var itemList = this.state.itemList;
    itemList.push(item);
    this.setState({itemList: itemList}, () => {
        alert(this.state.itemList.length);
    });
}
```

`setState` in React is not guaranteed to be synchronous; that is, you can't count on the state object to be set immediate after `setState` returns, which is why there's an optional callback argument to `setState` so you can be notified when all the state changes have taken effect.

Comment: Thanks, for pointing out, but I am looking for why my data is not rendered if you read the whole question, I am looking for the 'map' part of the question to be more specific.

Comment: There must be something else going on, as I could not reproduce your problem: https://jsbin.com/jadimequmo/edit?html,css,js,console,output